# Adjust height of content with percentages

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am currently creating a webpage for a client in the entertainment business. I thought it would be cool to make the page look like a movie theater, and on the screen the text would be displayed, however I have run into some issues.

To achieve my current progress I used the following for the background:

```
 body   {margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(../images/v1bg.png);
                    background-repeat:no-repeat;
                    background-size:cover;

                    }
```

Then for the content I did the following:

```
#content    {width:55%;
            height:280px;
            overflow-y:scroll;
             margin:0px auto;
        margin-top:5%;
        text-align:center;}
```

Now here is my issue, it lies in the content area.
My background adjusts based on the size of the viewer's device, so in most cases my height of 280px will not apply, and text will either overflow where I don't want it, or not cover the full screen in some cases. 
It works perfectly as it is, only in 1366 x 780 resolution.

To fix this I thought maybe I could just set the height of the content to a percentage, that doesn't work. When I turn the height into a percentage it morphs the background, and completely removed the height barrier making the content spill all down the screen, etc.

Any insight on how I can fix this is would be greatly appreciated.
Here's a link to what it currently looks like...

jqwebexamples.com/iAM_Talent/Version1/index.html

Comment: You need to set the height of html to 100% too. Afterwards, you should be able to set `#content`'s height to a percentage and have it behave the way you want. `html { height:100%; }`

Comment: @Marcelo Thanks! I had already set body's width & height to 100% but forgotten to set the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the css units 'vw' and 'vh'? Basically the define the size/distance relative to the viewport dimensions.